# Center collection of buttons using CSS

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I'm implementing a tab control using just HTML and CSS and have some mocked up HTML to generate a sample table, just for layout purposes. The buttons for the tab headings look fine, with one exception. When they wrap around, the next line starts from the left of the screen, ie the whole tab control heading is left aligned.

What I want is so the tab headings - as you add them - use a centered alignment, so they start to fill out the page from the center outwards. Ie if you only have a single heading, it should be 11% of the width, centred in the page. If you have two headings, they should each be 11% of the width, and overall the two of them should be centered.

How can I achieve this?

My HTML

```
public render() {
    return (
        <div className="Center-content">
            <div id="Home" className="Tab-content">
                 <h3>All Books</h3>
                 <p>Home is where the heart is..</p>
            </div>

            <div id="News" className="Tab-content">
                <h3>CR</h3>
                <p>Some news this fine day!</p> 
            </div>

            <div id="Contact" className="Tab-content">
                 <h3>SR</h3>
                 <p>Get in touch, or swing by for a cup of coffee.</p>
            </div>

            <div id="About" className="Tab-content">
                 <h3>CR-SR</h3>
                 <p>Who we are and what we do.</p>
            </div>

            <button className="Tab-link" >Heading1</button>
            <button className="Tab-link" >Heading2</button>
            <button className="Tab-link" >Heading3</button>
            <button className="Tab-link" >Heading4</button>
        </div>
    );
  }
```

My CSS

```
.Tab-link {
  background-color: #555;
  color: white;
  float: left;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 6px 6px;
  font-size: 14px;
  width: 11.11111%;
  border-top: 1px solid #777777;  
  border-right: 1px solid #777777;  
}

.Tab-link:hover {
  background-color: #777;
}

/* Style the tab content (and add height:100% for full page content) */
.Tab-content {
  color: white;
  display: none;
  padding: 100px 20px;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to wrap your link in an auxiliary wrapper and add `text-align:center` to it. And replace `float :left` property with `display:inline-block` for `.Tab-link`

Html:

```
<div class="text-center">
   <button class="Tab-link">Heading1</button>
   <button class="Tab-link">Heading2</button>
   <button class="Tab-link">Heading3</button>
   <button class="Tab-link">Heading4</button>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.Tab-link {
  background-color: #555;
  color: white;
  display:inline-block;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 6px 6px;
  font-size: 14px;
  width: 11.11111%;
  border-top: 1px solid #777777;  
  border-right: 1px solid #777777;  
}
```

Comment: Wow didnt even see that float left bit :-) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could just use `text-align: center` on parent element. Also you could use `min-width` on buttons instead of width.

```css
.Center-content {
  text-align: center;
}

.Tab-link {
  background-color: #555;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 6px 6px;
  font-size: 14px;
  border-top: 1px solid #777777;
  border-right: 1px solid #777777;
  min-width: 11%;
}

.Tab-link:hover {
  background-color: #777;
}

.Tab-content {
  padding: 100px 20px;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="Center-content">
  <div id="Home" class="Tab-content">
    <h3>All Books</h3>
    <p>Home is where the heart is..</p>
  </div>

  <div id="News" class="Tab-content">
    <h3>CR</h3>
    <p>Some news this fine day!</p>
  </div>

  <div id="Contact" class="Tab-content">
    <h3>SR</h3>
    <p>Get in touch, or swing by for a cup of coffee.</p>
  </div>

  <div id="About" class="Tab-content">
    <h3>CR-SR</h3>
    <p>Who we are and what we do.</p>
  </div>

  <button class="Tab-link">Heading1</button>
  <button class="Tab-link">Heading2</button>
  <button class="Tab-link">Heading3</button>
  <button class="Tab-link">Heading4</button>

</div>
```

Comment: I've tried that but it doesn't seem to work, the buttons still fill from the left

Comment: Is the result in demo not what you are looking for?